# Upload Images using Blogger Post Image API

Tags: php, api, upload, blogger, blogspot

Is there any way to upload images using blogger API? (https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using)
I have a web developer who is going through trouble to integrate Blogger API for uploading images to my site. I thought if I could be of any help at all to him.

Normally using Picasa the images upload to googleusercontent like this : 
[Link to a picasa image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jNYWWtRzAoEck5a8X6I8amPtwJxMoSIbaoyZFvC4kMGt5ar9BxdjDXxXz_VOPnwP1_PFdiiIuaBJ9Ek6IfY_Am3kywKFKgGJMESGyQmlZjSHI-Aaua3j8ITwarcWAhL4iXmz6-IOE6WqiBtdF5oRwxZdYqub2b4at-IjWhXlvTG6KiQYCJn5u5M33O1xqGVQujvUWJcwDYWFUqE3QzSuwVUUH8hR_uwVo1tlBXSDz_tCavNKfdOJee6uCluDHNOJtasa9JgxsxjELtaDoGNOPZJfwAXGO7T1_hijbF0Q_IddHQuYrxWUJP8-HmXcBPRsubzGy5JngKq5sATvspcIcdM1IP8IW3M8rQV-jzLyX7N89dL39BmwnaM1JuHZM3GBoTqCsuAXy4BAJQPzLUxJbgN5ffwtjRy6BaqTnzAmApG8xLjnCGjNYcnv4JTU6vu9tXFg54DVDsEb1H07lwZVJv5irS1mvK0RgXPQTkCEbHdClf6v-Zdj1W3Y0978EEwVNV-otuJxVsX_-EkRuBskyxyq5WIcAPFzcNABXjc5xLIt6wF67Jj97XiCMfP7YRIBP9VG_-ivPiTLwOG4s3RjVJfXwMs1rJEazzj16ewN=w459-h675-no)

But what I want is for it to be uploaded to this :
[Link to a image uploaded from Blogger post](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lYSwW8KKPq0/WmqxESiGLVI/AAAAAAABYoY/3e2BeY6pKIMq7Zi7iiFB6u0FIDY3SdsUACLcBGAs/s1600/004.jpg)

The developer is using PHP. I tried searching many sites but with no luck for a working version.
Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The images uploaded to Blogger directly via the website (having the URL format of `x.bp.blogspot.com`) are also saved on Picasa behind the scenes.

The domains used by these images (like `lh3.googleusercontent.com`, `3.bp.blogspot.com` ,`1.bp.blogspot.com`,`2.bp.blogspot.com`,`4.bp.blogspot.com`) are interchangeable in nature and all of them serve the same image.

For example, the image that is using the googleusercontent URL (For testing purpose, I uploaded an image using the Official Blogger Android app) -

`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VESDEmEh7EM/WpCZ_8qD_wI/AAAAAAAAYs0/XDWkxkEz7EUrGUBmpTSEKBGiynGrEKOygCHMYCw/s640/1519426035853.jpg`

Can also be accessed by using bp.blogspot.com URLs, like -

`https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-VESDEmEh7EM/WpCZ_8qD_wI/AAAAAAAAYs0/XDWkxkEz7EUrGUBmpTSEKBGiynGrEKOygCHMYCw/s640/1519426035853.jpg`

If you still want to exclusively use the `x.bp.blogspot.com` format URLs for images in the Blog post, you can write a custom logic in your PHP application to replace all references of `lh3.googleusercontent.com` (that you got after uploading the images via Picasa API) with `x.bp.blogspot.com` URLs before creating the post via the API)